# Object and ObjectManager circular dependency

Tags: object-oriented-design

As far as I know, circular dependencies are something to be avoided, yet I find myself often in a situation where I've got some `Object`, and an `ObjectManager`, that is supposed to "oversee" all the `Object`s, and provide methods to aggregate these `Object`'s and so on.

Example:

- `Object` that has a `position` and can move itself
- `ObjectManager` with methods like `getAllObjects` and `getAllObjectsAtPosition(x, y)`

`ObjectManager` needs to have a list of `Object` references, and `Object` needs a reference to `ObjectManager`, so it can notify the `ObjectManager` that it has changed its position  (so `ObjectManager` can, for example, update its hashmap with `position : Object` pairs, so `getAllObjectsAtPosition` is not linear)

Does it make to have a circular dependency here? If not, how should it be avoided?

Comment: One solution would be to put a GetPosition() function on the Object which is called by the ObjectManager when the manager needs to know positions. (see "The Hollywood Principle"  http://thephantomprogrammer.blogspot.com/2015/08/the-hollywood-principle-dont-call-us.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, circular dependencies are bad. The reason for that is you can't really change or even understand the one without the other, which kills maintainability.

Second, there are lots of ways to solve a circular dependency, but none is really generic. So you'll have to design your way around it case by case.

With your positions example, I offer you these alternatives:

1. Try to get the position out of `Object`, so it's only in `ObjectManager`.
2. Have the `ObjectManager` wrap all returned `Object` references with a Facade that updates `ObjectManager`'s own positions map when a `move` (or similar) is called on individual `Object`s.
3. Couple the `Object` with `ObjectManager` through an indirection, like a "listener" interface or event bus, or similar. I would note this complicates things significantly, so it should be the very last resort. This is basically "inverting" the dependencies in one direction.
4. Have the `Object` itself be a part of (inner class of) `ObjectManager`.
5. Design the whole thing differently, find different abstractions.

Also note that `Object` and `ObjectManager` are really bad names, I assume you picked those just for demonstrating the hierarchical relationship between them. Don't actually name things "Manager", that's so 2000s. :)

Comment: Thank you. Also, I wanted `Object` to fire an event whenever it changes its position, rather than keep an explicit reference to the manager. `ObjectManager` would listen to these events. I assume this is the third option on your list?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've meant. Again, having events still creates a coupling, and now this coupling is less visible. So it's a trade-off.